# How do I extract a paragraph from a website using JSoup?

Tags: jsoup

I need to grab the article-body from this URL:

[Aggie Headline](http://www.ncataggies.com//ViewArticle.dbml?DB_OEM_ID=24500&ATCLID=205346437)

I know that the article is inside the div class="article-body" tags. How can I extract it as a string?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ncataggies.com//ViewArticle.dbml?DB_OEM_ID=24500&ATCLID=205346437").get();
            Elements element = doc.getElementsByClass("article-body");
            String text = element.text();
             System.out.println(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ncataggies.com/ViewArticle.dbml?DB_OEM_ID=24500&ATCLID=205346437").get();
Element element = doc.select("div.article-body").first();
String text = element.text();
System.out.println(text);
```